# Can I use Hendrix to run Falcon app?

Tags: python, tornado, wsgi, falcon, hendrix

Hendrix is a WSGI compatible server written in Tornado. I was wondering if it can be used to run an app written in Falcon ?

Answer (score 2):

So found the solution. Created a python file according to hendrix's docs. And imported my app's wsgi callable there.